# PHP Delete all files older than x days in 2 folders

Tags: php

I'm tring to use this code to delete all files older than x days in 2 folder but I'm getting an error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC in E:\home\ca\web\cm\cache.php on line 6

Why?

```
<?php
$pastas = array("gallery-images/","resources/cache/");
foreach($pastas as $pasta){
   $this->deleteFrom($pasta);
}
public function deleteFrom($path){
$expiretime=10080; //expire time in minutes, 7 days = 7*24*60

$tmpFolder=$path.'/';
$fileTypes="*.*";

foreach (glob($tmpFolder . $fileTypes) as $Filename) {

// Read file creation time
$FileCreationTime = filectime($Filename);

// Calculate file age in seconds
$FileAge = time() - $FileCreationTime;

// Is the file older than the given time span?
if ($FileAge > ($expiretime * 0)){

// Now do something with the olders files...

echo "The file $Filename is older than $expiretime minutes\n";

//delete files:
unlink($Filename);
}

}
}
?>
```

Comment: `public` is unexpected. What didn't you understand about that error? `public` can only be used when defining class members. Remove it. (This comment reads more harshly than I expected, sorry about that).

Comment: Just delete `public` on line 6. It is intended to be used in an object-scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function definition is out of a class so you need to remove PUBLIC

```
public function deleteFrom($path){
```

to

```
function deleteFrom($path){
```

Also `$this->` is not correct you need to remove them and call the function as

```
deleteFrom($pasta);
```

Check here how Public, Private etc are used in PHP
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Answer (score 0):

this is because not using class here , so no need to  use `$this`  to call your function just use `deleteFrom()` please see the code below

```
foreach($pastas as $pasta){
   deleteFrom($pasta);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a class, you could write something like that :

```
$pastas = array("gallery-images/", "resources/cache/");

$File = new File();
foreach ($pastas as $pasta)
{
   $File->deleteFrom($pasta);
}

class File
{
  public function deleteFrom($path)
  {
    $expiretime=10080; //expire time in minutes, 7 days = 7*24*60

    $tmpFolder=$path.'/';
    $fileTypes="*.*";

    foreach (glob($tmpFolder . $fileTypes) as $Filename)
    {
      // Read file creation time
      $FileCreationTime = filectime($Filename);

      // Calculate file age in seconds
      $FileAge = time() - $FileCreationTime;

      // Is the file older than the given time span?
      if ($FileAge > ($expiretime * 0))
      {
        // Now do something with the olders files...
        echo "The file $Filename is older than $expiretime minutes\n";

        //delete files:
        unlink($Filename);
      }
    }
  }
}
```